# Unexpected ANTLR4 optimization with INT and FLOAT?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am writing a parser for the output of `Clasp` with `ANTLR 4`. The typical output is like the following:

```
clasp version 3.0.3
Reading from stdin
Solving...
Answer: 1
bird(a) bird(b) bird(c) penguin(d) bird(d)
Optimization: 7 0
Answer: 2
bird(a) bird(b) bird(c) penguin(d) bird(d) flies_abd(b) flies(b)
Optimization: 6 5
Answer: 3
bird(a) bird(b) bird(c) penguin(d) bird(d) flies_abd(c) flies(c)
Optimization: 2 5
Answer: 4
bird(a) bird(b) bird(c) penguin(d) bird(d) flies_abd(a) flies_abd(c) flies(a) flies(c)
Optimization: 1 10
Answer: 5
bird(a) bird(b) bird(c) penguin(d) bird(d) flies_abd(a) flies_abd(b) flies_abd(c) flies(a) flies(b) flies(c)
Optimization: 0 15
OPTIMUM FOUND

Models       : 5     
  Optimum    : yes
Optimization : 0 15
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.002s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
```

I have to check that `clasp` is version `3` so I am writing a grammar like the following:

```
/**
 * Define a grammar for Clasp 3's output.
 */
grammar Output;

@header {package ac.bristol.clasp.parser;}

output:
    version source solving answer* result separation statistics NEWLINE* EOF;

version: 'clasp version 3.' INT '.' INT NEWLINE;

source: 'Reading from stdin' NEWLINE # sourceSTDIN
    | 'Reading from ' path NEWLINE # sourceFile;

path:
    DRIVE? folder ( BSLASH folder )* filename # pathWindows
    | FSLASH? folder ( FSLASH folder )* filename # pathNIX;

folder:
    LETTER+ # genericFolder
    | DOTDOT # parentFolder
    | DOT # currentFolder;

solving: 'Solving...' NEWLINE;

filename:
    LETTER+ extension?;

extension:
    DOT LETTER*;

answer: 'Answer: ' INT NEWLINE // 
    model? NEWLINE // 
    'Optimization: ' INT ( SPACE INT )* NEWLINE;

model:
    fact ( SPACE fact )*;

fact:
    groundPredicate;

groundTermList:
    groundTerm ( COMMA groundTerm )*;

groundTerm:
    groundCompound | STRING | number | atom; // literal?

groundCompound:
    groundPredicate
    | groundExpression;

groundPredicate:
    IDENTIFIER ( LROUND groundTermList RROUND )?;

groundExpression:
    groundBits AND groundBits
    | groundBits OR groundBits
    | groundBits XOR groundBits;

groundBits:
    groundCompare GT groundCompare
    | groundCompare GE groundCompare
    | groundCompare LT groundCompare
    | groundCompare LE groundCompare;

groundCompare:
    groundItem EQ groundItem
    | groundItem NE groundItem;

groundItem:
    groundFactor PLUS groundFactor
    | groundFactor MINUS groundFactor;

groundFactor:
    groundUnary TIMES groundUnary
    | groundUnary DIVIDE groundUnary
    | groundUnary MOD groundUnary;

groundUnary:
    TILDE groundTerm
    | MINUS groundTerm;

atom:
    IDENTIFIER
    | QUOTED;

number:
    INT
    | FLOAT;

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

result: 'OPTIMUM FOUND' NEWLINE
    | 'SATISFIABLE' NEWLINE
    | 'UNKNOWN' NEWLINE;

separation:
    NEWLINE;

statistics:
    models optimum? optimization calls time cputime;

models: 'Models       : ' INT SPACE* NEWLINE;

optimum: '  Optimum    : yes' NEWLINE
    | '  Optimum    : no' NEWLINE;

optimization: 'Optimization : ' INT ( SPACE INT )* NEWLINE;
calls: 'Calls        : ' INT NEWLINE;
time: 'Time         : ' FLOAT 's (Solving: ' FLOAT 's 1st Model: ' FLOAT 's Unsat: ' FLOAT 's)' NEWLINE;
cputime: 'CPU Time     : ' FLOAT 's';

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AND:       '&';
BSLASH:    '\\';
COLON:     ':';
COMMA:     ',';
DIVIDE:    '/';
DOT:       '.';
DOTDOT:    '..';
EQ:        '==';
FSLASH:    '/';
GE:        '>=';
GT:        '>';
LE:        '<=';
LROUND:    '(';
LT:        '<';
MINUS:     '-';
MOD:       '%';
NE:        '!=';
OR:        '?';
PLUS:      '+';
RROUND:    ')';
SEMICOLON: ';';
SPACE:     ' ';
TILDE:     '~';
TIMES:     '*';
XOR:       '^';

DRIVE:      ( LOWER | UPPER ) COLON BSLASH?;
IDENTIFIER: LOWER FOLLOW*;
INT:        DIGIT+;
FLOAT:      DIGIT+ DOT DIGIT+;
NEWLINE:    '\r'? '\n';
QUOTED:     '\'' ( ~[\'\\] | ESCAPE )+? '\'';
STRING:     '"' ( ~["\\] | ESCAPE )+? '"';

fragment DIGIT:      [0] | NONZERO;
fragment ESCAPE:     '\\' [btnr"\\] | '\\' [0-3]? [0-7]? [0-7] | '\\' 'u' [0-9a-fA-F] [0-9a-fA-F] [0-9a-fA-F] [0-9a-fA-F];
fragment FOLLOW:     LOWER | UPPER | DIGIT | UNDERSCORE;
fragment LETTER:     LOWER | UPPER | DIGIT | SPACE;
fragment LOWER:      [a-z];
fragment NONZERO:    [1-9];
fragment UNDERSCORE: [_];
fragment UPPER:      [A-Z];
```

Notice that there is no rule to `skip` some parts of the input stream because I want to check every single character. 
Also notice that I have a terminal rule for `INT`ever and one for `FLOAT`, `INT` is defined before `FLOAT`, `FLOAT`s are defined like in Prolog.

The rule that parses the first line of the above example is the following:

```
version: 'clasp version 3.' INT '.' INT NEWLINE;
```

because it I have to check that the `clasp` major version number being used is 3, than I have to consume the rest of the line reading the minor version number, a dot, the build number and the newline (without spaces or whatsoever).
Unfortunately, I get the following warning message, that makes me think that ANTLR is recognizing the minor version number, the dot and the build number as a `FLOAT`:

```
line 1:16 mismatched input '0.3' expecting INT
```

Could you please explain me what is going on?
Am I assuming something that I shouldn't?
Or is it `ANTLR` that is applying an unneeded optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR breaks your input into tokens, and only after that parses the tokens. Your use of `'clasp version 3.'` in a parser rule implicitly defines an anonymous token that matches that string of text. The text following that token starts with `0.0`, which matches a float. The lexer has no idea that the parser will be in the `version` rule at that point; it merely chooses the longest token starting at the current position, and `0.0` as a `FLOAT` is longer than `0` as an `INT`. I recommend the following:

1. Separate your grammar into a `parser grammar OutputParser;` and a `lexer grammar OutputLexer;` In your parser grammar, use the `tokenVocab` option to indicate which lexer defines your tokens. This separation will force you to define real tokens for everything the grammar is using.

   ```
   options {
     tokenVocab = OutputLexer;
   }
   ```
2. Either use a `FLOAT` instead of `INT '.' INT`, or create a new token to represent a version:

   ```
   VERSION
     : DIGIT+ DOT DIGIT+ DOT DIGIT+
     ;
   ```

Comment: Hi Sam (@280Z28), thanks for the helpful explanation! My misunderstanding was probably due to the fact that I was considering the parser as a basic recursively descendant parser, with the productions that choose the tokens to accept. Anyway I think I will turn `INT DOT INT` into `FLOAT` as a temporary solution to make the warning disappear (I am not using these numbers anywhere else, after all) but I will investigate how to separate parser grammar and lexer grammar because learning something new is always a good thing! Many thanks for your help!